# Proving that any element of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ can be expressed as $\pm\exp(z)$.

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

I would like to show that any element $N\in\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ can be represented in the following form
\begin{align}
N=\pm\exp(z)~~~~\text{ for } ~~~~~z\in\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R}).
\end{align}
The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ is that of real traceless $2\times 2$ matrices. I (for personal reasons) choose to use  the basis
\begin{align}
\tau_1=\begin{pmatrix}0&&-1\\-1&&0\end{pmatrix},~~~\tau_2=\begin{pmatrix}1&&0\\0&&-1\end{pmatrix},~~~\tau_3=\begin{pmatrix}0&&1\\-1&&0\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Any element  $z\in\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ can then be expressed as a linear combination of these matrices; $z=z^m\tau_m$ with $z^m$ the local coordinates of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and I have used the Einstein summation convention. Thus, in this basis an arbitrary $z$ is 
\begin{align}
z=\begin{pmatrix} z_2&&z_3-z_1\\-z_1-z_3&&-z_2\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

To compute the exponential first observe that $z^2=\omega^2 I$ where $\omega^2:=z_1^2+z_2^2-z_3^2$ and $I$ is the $2\times 2$ identity. I think we should split it into three cases where $\omega^2=0, \omega^2<0$ and $\omega^2>0$. I will only do the case $\omega^2>0$ for brevity. Computing the exponential explicitly we have
\begin{align}
\exp(z)&=\exp\bigg(\begin{pmatrix} z_2&&z_3-z_1\\-z_1-z_3&&-z_2\end{pmatrix}\bigg)\\
&=I+z+\frac{1}{2!}\omega^2I+\frac{1}{3!}\omega^2z+\frac{1}{4!}\omega^4I+\frac{1}{5!}\omega^4z+\cdots\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\omega^{2n}}{(2n)!}I+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\omega^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}z\\
&=\cosh(\omega)I+\frac{1}{\omega}\sinh(\omega)z\\
&=\begin{pmatrix} \cosh(\omega)+\frac{z_2}{\omega}\sinh(\omega)&&\frac{z_3-z_1}{\omega}\sinh(\omega)\\\\-\frac{z_3+z_1}{\omega}\sinh(\omega)&&\cosh(\omega)-\frac{z_2}{\omega}\sinh(\omega)\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}.
\end{align}
Now I need to show that any $N$ can be written as $\pm(1)$ but I am not sure how to do this part. I thought I could try and write 
\begin{align}
N=\begin{pmatrix} a&&b\\c&&d\end{pmatrix} ,~~~~ ad-bc=1
\end{align}
and solve the resulting system of equations but I don't think this is how it is done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $A\in\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb R)$
and $B\in\text{GL}_2(\Bbb R)$ then $B^{-1}AB\in\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb R)$
and $\exp(B^{-1}AB)=B^{-1}\exp(A)B$. Therefore, if the conclusion is true for some
$N$ then it is true for all $N'$ conjugate to $N$.

If $N$ has two distinct real eigenvalues, then it is conjugate to
$$\pm\pmatrix{a&0\\0&a^{-1}}=\pm\exp\pmatrix{\ln a&0\\0&-\ln a}$$
for some $a>0$.

If $N$ has non-real eigenvalues, then it is conjugate to
$$\pmatrix{\cos t&-\sin t\\\sin t&\cos t}=\exp\pmatrix{0&-t\\t&0}.$$

If $N$ has two equal real eigenvalues then either it is $\pm I=\pm\exp(O)$ or is conjugate to
$$\pm\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}=\pm\exp\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}.$$

Comment: Thank you, your method is very nice. I also wanted to show that the exponential covers $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ except for a two dimensional manifold in $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ consisting of elements of the form $$\begin{pmatrix} -1-ac&&a^2\\-c^2&&ac-1\end{pmatrix}=N\begin{pmatrix} -1&&1\\0&&-1\end{pmatrix}N^{-1},~~~N=\begin{pmatrix}a&&b\\c&&d\end{pmatrix}\in\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}).$$

I thought the Lie algebra formalism would help here, which is why i chose that route. Would you know how I would go about proving this ?

Comment: @NormalsNotFar Recall the eigenvalues of $\exp(A)$ are the exponentials of the eigenvalues of $A$. If $A$ is real with trace zero, then its eigenvalues are $\pm\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is real or purely imaginary. The only way to get negative eigenvalues for $\exp(A)$ is when $A$ has distinct eigenvalues $\pm m\pi i$ with $m$ odd. That means that $\exp(A)=-I$. So no other matrix with negative eigenvalues is the exponential of a trace zero real matrix.

Comment: Please forgive me for this stupid question, but I don't see how this relates to my above comment...

Comment: I have thought about it more and I understand the points you were making now. However I have another question. I would still have to show that  $$\begin{pmatrix}-1-ac&&a^2\\-c^2&&ac-1 \end{pmatrix}$$ are the only elements of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ with negative eigenvalues (e-values are -1) wouldn't I?

Comment: Is that actually true?

Comment: I am not, sure.. it is a pretty strong result. Or are you asking if the claim in my first comment is true? I got the result from the book linked below page 13, although they claimed it for $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ and $(a,c)$ were complex so that the said manifold was 4 dimensional instead of 2. I am hoping that it is true for $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ by uncomplexifying.
$$~$$
https://www.amazon.com/Ideas-Methods-Supersymmetry-Supergravity-Gravitation/dp/0750305061

Comment: Here is a counter example; $$N=\begin{pmatrix}-2&&1\\1&&-1\end{pmatrix}\in \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}).$$
This has eigenvalues of $\lambda=-\frac{3}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$. So my claim must be false...

Comment: A simpler counterexample: $\pmatrix{-2&0\\0&-1/2}$.

Comment: Ok so I can only say that elements of SL(2,R) with trace < -2 cannot be represented as an exponential (such matrices always have distinct negative e-values).