# What is in the image of the exponential of $\frak{sl}(n,\mathbb{R}$)? What do you need to get all of $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R}$)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2468650/490301) discusses how $\mathrm{S}L(2,\mathbb{R}$) coincides with $\pm\exp(z)$ with $z\in \frak{sl}(n,\mathbb{R}$) (the real traceless matrices). Is it known what happens for $n>2$?

Namely, one can represent all invertible matrices with determinant $1$ and trace greater than or equal to $-2$. Also, just by providing a sign (more precisely, up to the center of the group, which is $\{ I, -I\}$) one is able to obtain all of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ ).

Is such a result known for the general case of $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$, which characterizes the image of the exponential and what one needs to "add" in order to obtain the entire group (i.e. what is the "minimal" set $A\subseteq G$ such that $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R}) = A \exp(\frak{sl}(n,\mathbb{R}))$ )?

I would also be interested in the more general question regarding classical Lie groups, although this would already be a great help towards a greater understanding of what happens in the exponential (even just for $n=3$).

Comment: Do you already know how to prove it in the easier case of $SL(n,\mathbb C)$?

Comment: Not too familiar. I understand the $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ case by listing all conjugacy classes: a matrix has two distinct real (both positive or negative) eigenvalues, a matrix has two distinct imaginary eigenvalues, a matrix has one eigenvalue $\pm 1$ (which is $\pm \mathbb{Id}$ or the unipotent matrices with eigenvalues $\pm 1$).

Comment: In terms of addressing which Lie groups are exponential, the paper https://www.heldermann-verlag.de/jlt/jlt15/wuestla2e.pdf seems to provide a complete list for the simple case (which includes $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$) and does not list its centerless version $\mathrm{PSL}(n,\mathbb{R}$. So I'm guessing that at the very least $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is not equal to its center times the image of the exponential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if the complete answer is known, but the interior and the exterior of the image $E$ of the exponential map are known:

1. The interior of $E$ consists of all matrices in $SL(n,\mathbb R)$ which have no negative eigenvalues.
2. The exterior of $E$ consists of all matrices in $A\in SL(n,\mathbb R)$ which have at least one negative eigenvalue of odd multiplicity.
3. Thus, the boundary of $E$ consists of matrices $A\in SL(n,\mathbb R)$ such that some eigenvalues of $A$ are negative but all such eigenvalues have even multiplicity. For instance, $A=Diag(-1/2,-1/2,-2, -2, 1)$ is an example.

This result is due to M.Nishikawa but his paper does not seem to be accessible. Another proof can be found in

*Đoković, Dragomir Ž.*, [**The interior and the exterior of the image of the exponential map in classical Lie groups**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(88)90134-2), J. Algebra 112, No. 1, 90-109, Corrigendum 115, No. 2, 521 (1988). [ZBL0638.22006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0638.22006).

He also gives a description of the image $E$ of the exponential map for $SL(n,\mathbb C)$ but it is a bit too hard to state and you can find it in his paper. The set $E$ is open and dense (for some reason, he does not say "open" but it is open because the exponential map is holomorphic).

Comment: This seems like almost exactly what I was looking for. Does this mean that the boundary are all the matrices which have no negative eigenvalues of odd multiplicity? Furthermore, how could one act on the matrices with no negative eigenvalues to produce a matrix with (at least one) negative eigenvalues of odd multiplicity? This would answer the second part of the question.

Comment: @AnotherUser: (1) That would be wrong. (2) I am unsure what you mean by "act". You can compute its Jordan Normal form, change some of the eigenvalues and then conjugate back, for instance.

Comment: (1) I see, thanks for the update. (2) I meant something like for $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ where a product of an element of $\exp(\frak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ with an element of $Z(\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})) = \{\mathbb{1}, -\mathbb{1}\}$ coincides with the entire group. In the simplest case, one could find a minimal (possibly non-redundant) set $S$ such that a product of $S$ with the image of the exponential coincides with the entire group for $n>2$.

Comment: So in this case, for any matrix $X_+$ with positive eigenvalues, there would be a matrix $P\in S$ such that $X_- = P X_+$ has one negative eigenvalue with odd multiplicity.

Comment: @AnotherUser: On general grounds, there is a finite subset $\{g_1,...,g_k\}\subset G=SL(n, \mathbb R)$ such that $\cup_{i} g_iE=G$. Off hand, I do not know what this finite subset is.

Comment: That's great, would you be able to point to some references to start my search?